# ufw blocks incoming FTP traffic (on port DPT=44745)

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ftp, ufw

I have JVM app which is dealing as client with FTP, it works fine when ufw is disabled, but when I enable ufw with:

```
ufw allow ftp
```

Check status output is then:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (medium)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

My app looks like this (login to FTP, list files, get file), and it gets stuck STUCK_HERE when ufw is enabled:

```
fun execute(){
    val ftpClient = FTPClient()
    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("example.com"))
    val loginResult = ftpClient.login("secretLogin", "secretPass")
    val stockFile: FTPFile? = ftpClient.listFiles().firstOrNull {
        it.name.startsWith("stock")
    }.also {
        println("FTP stock file name:${it?.name}, size:${it?.size}, type:${it?.type}")
    }
    // <- STUCK_HERE, this is not called
    stockFile?.let { ftpFile ->
        val outStream = BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(Const.stockCsvName))
        outStream.use {
            ftpClient.retrieveFile(ftpFile.name, it)
        }
    }
    ftpClient.disconnect()
}
```

So I checked ufw logs on my client machine and it seems that incoming traffic so blocked:

```
May  3 11:26:20 kernel: [2562852.155804] [UFW ALLOW] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=OOO.OOO.OOO.OOO DST=III.III.III.III LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60824 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=44076 DPT=21 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
May  3 11:26:23 kernel: [2562855.178073] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm SRC=III.III.III.III DST=OOO.OOO.OOO.OOO LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=48578 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20 DPT=44745 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

And it's most probably by incoming FTP traffic port which seems to be `DPT=44745` - which my ufw does not allow.

My first question: **the port `DPT=44745` is so called [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)**?

The other question: **can I deal with it somehow**? I mean keept ufw up but allow FTP?

So far I only found [flaws of FTP security](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-ftp-port-requests-challenge-firewall-security/), but it did not get me to solution.

Whole setup runs on DigitalOceans' VPS armed with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Is ufw config from server or client? If it is on the server, you should limit ports for PASV mode and open these ports with ufw. On client there should be no need to setup anything as long as you are using PASV mode transfer.

Comment: it's from client (where my JVM app is running)

Comment: I believe that on client, you do not need to have any incoming ports open. Incoming connections should only be allowed for established connections, and I think ufw should that already configured. If you make PASSIVE ftp connections, ftp server should not try to make a connection towards client. So, make sure you make passive ftp connections, and remove all incoming ports (21, 22) on client.